# How to load 100K data to a table with spring boot( server side) and Angular (front end)

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i have a problem in loading data from back end to from end without delaying the client side .. i use spring boot for back end and angular 7 for front end.. the problem is when i submit the request from front end to load all the data from back end it takes 55 seconds to load  the data. its too much waiting.. i wanna know is there any idea to do this process faster..

i have already done all the coding for loading data from back end to front end.. there are no any errors or any problem of loading data from back end to front end.. but the problem is loading time is too much i want to speed this process

this is application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/siri?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =sanu
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
```

this is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parts")
public class Parts implements SuperEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "map")
    @TableGenerator(name = "map", table = "Id_Gen", pkColumnName = 
   "Tables_Names", valueColumnName = "Gen_keys", pkColumnValue = 
   "PartsDTO", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private int id;
    private String partName;
    private String partNumber;
    private String barCode;
    private String brand;
    private String partType;
    private String country;
    private String vehicleModel;
    private String packSize;
    private String location;
    private String rackNo;
    private String roq;
    private String rql;
    @Column(name = "imageUrl1")
    private String imageUrl1;
    @Column(name = "imageUrl2")
    private String imageUrl2;
    @Column(name = "imageUrl3")
    private String imageUrl3;
    @Column(name = "imageUrl4")
    private String imageUrl4;
    private Blob image;
    private Blob image1;
    private Blob image2;
    private Blob image3;
    private String warranty;
    private Date adedDate;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Catogary catogary;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "Parts_FuelType",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "part_ID", 
    referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fuel_Type", 
    referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<FuelType> fuelTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parts", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = 
    FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<OrderDetails> orderDetail = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parts", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = 
    FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("date DESC")
    private List<Bulk> bulks = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

this is Crud Repo

```
public interface PartsRepo extends CrudRepository<Parts, Integer> {
    Parts findPartsByBarCode(String barCode) throws Exception;
    List<Parts> findPartsByPartNameContaining(String partName) throws Exception;
    List<Parts> findPartsByPartNumberContaining(String partNumber) throws Exception;
    Long countByBarCodeAndFuelTypes(String barCode, FuelType t) throws Exception;
    Parts findPartsByPartNumber(String partNumber) throws Exception;
}
```

this is controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getAll")
public List<PartsDTO> getAllParts() {
    try {
        return partsService.getAllParts();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

from this it get nearly 1minits to load all the data to the front end html table i wanna know what is the speediest way to load all the data (100K) data to the html table quickly

[image]

Comment: you must add paging for your data, should not load all in one request

Comment: When you have lots of data to display, you need to use paging. You already are, but this is client-side paging, which means that angular needs to process **all records** and page them, which is very slow. You should do paging server-side.

Comment: then please explain me how to do server side paging in spring boot

Answer (score 0):

You really should add server-side paging if you need to load 100K records.

Spring-Boot allows you to create paging out of the box.

Your `repository` should extend `PagingAndSortingRepository`:

```
public interface PartsRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Parts, Integer> {
    Page<Parts> getAllPartsPage(Pageable pageable, //whatever @Param you need here);
}
```

And your `controller` should accept `Pageable` parameter:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getAll")
public Page<PartsDTO> getAllPartsPageable(@SortDefault("id (or whatever field you need)") Pageable pageable) {
    try {
        return partsService.getAllPartsPage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Checkout `Pageable` interface [description](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html).

Also, here's a nice [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting) about spring-boot pagination.